# Can I run two tomcat instances on the same machine?

Tags: java, tomcat

Can I run two Tomcat servers with two different ports on the same machine? Will it create any problem? When I run a tomcat it will create the `javaw.exe` file in the task manager.

Comment: Task manager sidenote: it only list processess. The javaw.exe you see is only the name of the executable launched but it's not creating any new file. Is like when you create two instances of a class. The exe file is like the class and the processes are the instances :)

Comment: If any of these solved your problem, you should probably accept the one that worked.

Answer (score 69):

Apart from changing `Connector port` for `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` described in one of the answers below.

I think it requires to change Server port for 'Shutdown'

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

and also `AJP` port no.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

If you want to run multiple tomcat instances in parallel.

Comment: Good and neath answer, just as an add on, besides Connector port, Shutdwon port, and AJP port, you may want to change Connector port for SSL as well:  <Connector port="8443" , changing all 8443 ocourrencies to some else in server.xml. Once it's very likely you will use SSL at certain point.

Answer (score 31):

Yes !. You can. You need to change your port to have another instance.

To do so follow the steps.

1.) Locate server.xml in {Tomcat installation folder}\ conf \

2.)Find following similar statement

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8180 -->
    <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

3.) About Tomcat’s server.xml file cites it’s runs on port 8080. Change the Connector port=”8080″ port to any other port number.

For example

```
<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

4) Edit and save the server.xml file. Restart Tomcat. Done

Comment: Do not forget about SHUTDOWN port (at the very beginning of `server.xml` config file. Also you can use this tutorial -- http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server/

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that's absolutely fine. I've done it on numerous occasions. You'll need to check *all* the ports you're using for Tomcat though. I can't remember whether it still has a special "local control" port, but if so those will need to be different too.

Comment: @krishna, note that if you find an answer useful, you can (and should) upvote it by clicking on the up arrow on its left :-)

Comment: And one additional recommendation. You will probably wish to create separate log files for each instance of tomcat. In this case use -Dlog4j.properties to pass log configuration for each tomcat instance.

Comment: With "all ports" Jon means at least Non-SSL, SSL, shutdown and AJP.

Comment: I am able to run it by changing the port numbers... Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In general we also set CATALINA_HOME property. so startup script first reads catalina_home and than from it figures out rest of the path. If this environment variable is set and if you try to run tomcat from any copy-paste tomcat installation location, you will get tomcat running which is pointed by CATALINA_HOME.

So while running two tomcat from same machine, remove the CATALINA_HOME property. That way it will set the CATALINA_HOME property based on directory from which you are running the startup script.

Answer (score 7):

Adding a few pointers to detailed instructions on how to accomplish that:

1. [Step by step](http://java.dzone.com/articles/running-multiple-tomcat) Running Multiple Tomcat Instances on One Server.
2. An [older version](http://kief.com/running-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server.html) of the above.
3. [Explanation](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/08/multiple-tomcat-instances-on-single.html) of various environment variables & folders that play a role in such setup.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my expperience/process of making two Tomcats (Tom1 and Tom2) running on Windows:

1. Setup Tomcat according to http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html
2. However, Tom1 starts up fine, but not Tom2.
3. So in addition to the above, in server.xml, make/change the following (on Tomcat 6.0.44, JDK 1.6.0_45):

   Line 22: Tom1 shutdown port = 9001
   Line 22: Tom2 shutdown port = 9002

   Line 53: Tom1 service name = "Catalina1"
   Line 53: Tom2 service name = "Catalina2"

   Line 69: Tom1 connector (http) = 9001
   Line 69: Tom2 connector (http) = 9002

   Line 71: Tom1 redirect port = 8443
   Line 71: Tom2 redirect port = 8444

   Line 90: Tom1 connector (ajp) = 8009
   Line 90: Tom1 redirect = 8443
   Line 90: Tom2 connector (ajp) = 8010
   Line 90: Tom2 redirect = 8444

   Line 102: Tom1 engine name = "Catalina1"
   Line 102: Tom2 engine name = "Catalina2"
4. Starting up each server

Voila!

Answer (score 3):

I've faced a similar situation and the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21945707/3541057), solves it in much crisp and simple fashion.

> Let's say that you have only one Tomcat folder located in C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39, and that you wish to run two instances from it.
>
> Make sure that you have CATALINA_HOME system/user variable set, and
>   pointing to C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39
>
> Create a folder C:\instance1. Copy conf, webapps and temp folders from
>   C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39 and paste them to C:\instance1. You can delete
>   contents from webapps and temp folders located under instance1, but
>   don't touch conf contents. Now copy>paste C:\instance1 and rename it
>   to instance2. That way, both instance1 and instance2 will have the
>   same content. Go to C:\instance2\conf, edit server.xml and change the
>   numbers of these ports (I marked those as XXXX):
>
> Deploy whatever you want into instance1\webapps and instance2\webapps
>   Create the following 4 batch files under C:\
>
> instance1_startup.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
>
> set CATALINA_BASE=C:\instance1
>
> cd "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin"
>
> set TITLE=My Tomcat Instance 01
>
> call startup.bat %TITLE%
> ```
>
> instance1_shutdown.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
>
> set CATALINA_BASE=C:\instance1
>
> cd "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin"
>
> call shutdown.bat
> ```
>
> instance2_startup.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
>
> set CATALINA_BASE=C:\instance2
>
> cd "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin"
>
> set TITLE=My Tomcat Instance 02
>
> call startup.bat %TITLE%
> ```
>
> instance2_shutdown.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
>
> set CATALINA_BASE=C:\instance2
>
> cd "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin"
>
> call shutdown.bat
> ```
>
> Run instance1_startup.bat and instance2_startup.bat, hopefully it
>   should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can run unlimited instances of tomcat on your server/pc, ofcourse you need to define each one with different port.

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed here, you can either omit the CATALINA_HOME environment variable and use the catalina.sh script to manage your container's life cycle or you could define another variable like CATALINA_HOME1 to point to the new tomcat's installation directory and modify it's catalina.sh script to use CATALINA_HOME1 instead of the original CATALINA_HOME reference.

In any case, you could avoid it all together by omitting any environment variable named CATALINA_HOME references and just link to the corresponding tomcat's catalina.sh script.

**example:**

```
cd /usr/sbin
ln -s /usr/local/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/catalina.sh catalina1
ln -s /usr/share/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/catalina.sh catalina2
```

Then start your tomcats like this (from anywhere):

```
catalina1 start
catalina2 start
```

Tom