# How to run multiple tomcat instances in parallel?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to run multiple `tomcat` instances in parallel in the same machine.
Therefore trying to change the default port, but it does not work.

server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           compression="on"
           />

<Connector port="8019" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

On startup, I get the error: `JAVA_BIND<null>:8080 already in use`

What might be missing? Which steps have to be taken to run in parallel?

**UPDATE:** The problem is that  the machine defines the environment variable as follows:

```
CATALINA_HOME = d:\apache\
```

Thus any tomcat installation points to the same directory on launch.

How could I change this?

Comment: what about the shutdown port?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4678470/3841803

Comment: Delete the system variable. It is enough to run the startup script from the Tomcat home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CATALINA_HOME` is an environment variable which, if not set in advance, will resolve to the parent directory of the startup script you are executing. Therefore I recommend you delete that variable from your environment and let Tomcat's startup procedure resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The errors means that this port `8080` is already in use by your running Tomcat instance.

If you want to run another tomcat instance, you just need to run it on another port `9090` for example, just take a copy of the tomcat folder in another place, and in your `server.xml` file change that `8080` to `9090`.

Comment: That's what I did and as described above it results in the error stated.

Comment: Did you run it from eclipse or any other IDE?

Comment: No it's tomcat standalone, no ide involved.

Answer (score 0):

While running multiple tomcat instances change below port

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

also

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

**Edited**: remove CALALINE_HOME from environmental variables. If CALALINE_HOME is not present tomcat will take parent directory as CALALINE_HOME.

Comment: Tomcat does not complain about `8005`, but `8080` which was already changed to `8090` and `8009` to `8019` above.

Comment: Tomcat uses Shutdown port as well and if you change, hopefully it will work.. Please try once, if not then we can check further. But i am sure it will work after changing Shutdown port as well.

Comment: Please have a look at my update, I found the cause is an environment variable `CALALINE_HOME`

Comment: remove CALALINE_HOME from env variables. If CALALINE_HOME is not present tomcat will take current location.