# how to setup Thingworx 7.0 for high availability?

Tags: thingworx

I am currently trying to instantiate 2 or more instances of thingworx on a single machine for trying Thingworx for high availability.Can you specify the different software along with their version that are required to setup  Thingworx 7.0 for high availability?.Are their any tutorials that can help me with the setup?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use two or more ThingWorx instances on same machine then you can install two or more Apache tomcat server on same machine with different ports (check stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678077/can-i-run-two-tomcat-instances-on-the-same-machine) for the same) and deploy ThingWorx on both of them.

And you can refer [Installing and Upgrading ThingWorx to install ThingWorx](http://support.ptc.com/help/thingworx_hc/thingworx_7_hc/#page/ThingWorx_Core_Help_Center%2FThingWorxHelpCenterDITAFiles%2FGettingStarted%2FInstallingandUpgrading%2FInstallingandUpgrading.html%23) guide to install ThingWorx.

Comment: Do not forget to up vote, if any answer makes you happy :D

Answer (score 1):

To decrease the duration of outage for critical internet of things systems ,you can configure thingwrox core for high availability .This requires a complex setup which you can configure by this guide 
http://support.ptc.com/WCMS/files/171336/en/ThingWorx_7.0_High_Availability_Administrators_Guide.pdf