# How to migrate two tomcat applications from separate servers to a single server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a question about best practice around Tomcat installation.

Now we have two applications on separated server, with one tomcat instance for each application.

We want to merge the application into the same server, but I don't know the best practice to do that.

I see two possibilities:

1. I have one tomcat per application
2. I have one tomcat for all applications

Do you have experiences to share with me. I want to make sure that we proceed with the best option.

Comment: There's no "best" (and almost never is), there is only "best for". You don't give us enough context to answer what is the "for" here, and even then I would expect that the answer would be generally opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have only one Tomcat, however if there's a valid reason why need two instances you will have to run them on different ports, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678470/2601113) answer if you need help.

Note: I've never needed to run two instances of Tomcat on the same server, not even one time I had one app on https and other apps on http, almost everything is possible with the correct configuration.