# Is it possible to use Apache Tomcat server in both IDE Eclipse and Netbeans in a PC?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, netbeans

I have installed both Eclipse and Netbeans and alreday set-up path of jdk .now i want to set different version of Apache tomcat server like as apche tomcat 9.0 and 8.5  in  Eclipse and Netbeans respectively .But its shows error. In Eclipse Server Can't be startd . I have used differnt server port and shutdown port for two servers.but it doent work

Comment: Yes, If the Catalina Connectors  are separate and on separate ports. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678077/can-i-run-two-tomcat-instances-on-the-same-machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run two tomcat instances on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678077/can-i-run-two-tomcat-instances-on-the-same-machine)